# Lowest Latency Sound Card

Tags: sound-card, latency

I'm using a sound card for reading analogue signals and for the ADC component. I need extremely low latency (<1ms). Is the sound card the right way to go or can you get better results with a custom ADC component with 0 buffer?

Whats the best available sound card?
Whats the best interface (USB/Firewire/PCI)?
Can you set the buffer size to 0?

Appreciate any help on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of the USB/Firewire/PCI sound cards from audio production hardware companies should meet your needs.

- [MOTU](http://www.motu.com/products)
- [M-audio](http://m-audio.com)
- [Apogee](http://www.apogeedigital.com/products/)

MOTU's products have 'zero latency' monitoring, but you should be able to get down to the 1-2 MS range for input to your system.

Comment: thxs nick...any idea how these compare to the create emu 0204? How come all these seem to use a 1ms buffer?

Comment: I've heard the emu products are very good as well.

Answer (score 0):

Asus Xonar Essence STX provides up to 1ms Latency

https://www.asus.com/Sound_Cards_and_DigitaltoAnalog_Converters/Xonar_Essence_STX/

Im currently running this $200 sound card on Win 7 64 bit, very pleased, not sure about Win 8. Many configurable options and features, I recommend this sound card to anybody looking for the best of the best, software is decent and I've never had a problem. Sound quality is unbelievable, definitely worth the money.